# Ubuntu Desktop won't install from CD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

I keep reading that I need to install Ubuntu Desktop by booting it from a CD.  Well every time I try I get to the section where it ask if I want to install alongside Windows 7 and I then click continue.  Then the program ejects the CD and restarts the computer into windows.  I'm using a laptop with windows 7 64bit 8GB memory and 500GB hard drive.  I've made a partition for Ubuntu and still the same thing keeps happening.  What am I doing wrong?